# Chopper Java: what is wrong with this?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class linecounter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter a line of integers");
        Scanner chopper = first Scanner();
        int x =chopper.nextInt();
        while (chopper.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println(chopper.nextInt());
        }
    }
}
```

This keeps telling me that a ';' is expected on the line that starts with scanner chopper, what could the problem be?

P.S. Do you know how i can get it to keep count of how many integers were typed in?

Comment: `Scanner chopper = first Scanner();` doesn't have any meaning. It should be `Scanner chopper = new Scanner();`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Minor note: `Scanner` must have something to scan so this class doesn't have non-argument constructor. OP probably want to scan from standard input.

Comment: You seriously need to start with a basic Java tutorial. This question is extremely poor.

Comment: @Pshemo that's not posted anywhere in the code, so we are not sure. Anyway, the problem is a typo after all, just that.

Comment: So you try to use `Scanner` but have not tried to search any example on the net about it and come here to ask us to teach you? Sorry, that's not how this site works.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza excuse me but i am a first time user, my mistake

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza True, it is not said anywhere but since OP is printing on standard output information to "*Enter a line of integers*" we can assume with hight probability that input should also come from standard input. Anyway I agree with you that this problem should be treated as typo and most probably closed as off-topic.

Comment: @Pshemo that would turn the application into an infinite loop. Making the code *able to compile* won't solve the real problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written `first Scanner()` instead of `new Scanner(System.in)`.

You need to specify an input source, and since you want the user to input the numbers, you should use `System.in` as argument.

Comment: +1, but he fixed the second error.

Comment: @TheGuy: Thank you, removed the second part of the answer.

Comment: -1: Using `new Scanner(System.in)` in this case would turn the application into an infinite loop.

Comment: @Luiggi: That downvote makes no sense to me at all. Maybe OP wants that as a step to get to know `Scanner` and input. It is obviously nowhere near a complete program anyway.

Comment: @Keppil Do you know how i can get it to keep count of how many integers were typed in?

Comment: Your solution add a new problem, that's why I don't consider it as a real solution and vote against it.

Comment: @Luiggi: It definitely doesn't. I guess we won't agree here though, so let's just leave it at that.

Comment: @user: Sure, but that is another question, and shouldn't be added to this one. Try to solve it on your own first, and post a new question if you run into any specific problems.

Comment: Making it compile doesn't mean to solve the whole problem...

Answer (score 0):

Why does your code say `first Scanner();` instead of `new Scanner();`?  I think that's the problem.

Comment: There's a vote to close for typographical problems, you know...

Comment: @SimonT i changed that and it gave me this errorerror: no suitable constructor found for Scanner()

Comment: @user3557432 you need to put `System.in` as an argument in the constructor; see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
Scanner chopper = first Scanner();
```

should be:

```
Scanner chopper = new Scanner(System.in);
```

`new Scanner(System.in)` creates a new `Scanner` object that take input from the console, `first Scanner()` is syntactically incorrect and is what gives the error.

Comment: Do you know how i can get it to keep count of how many integers were typed in?

Comment: @user3557432 [Ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). If you do, make sure to include a _lot_ of details.